# Does Hash value differs between On prem SQL and Azure SQL when we try to find hash of a same column with same value?

Tags: sql, azure, hash, hashbytes

I tried to find a hash of a value in on prem SQL, it gave -0x7100C195B6C4050ADEC642295F50C0B8
but when I tried to execute the same hash for azure SQL am getting a different hash. my code is
select *,
cast(HASHBYTES('MD5',CONCAT('AU_DWH','2527',ID as varbinary) as Hask_key  from tablename